# Installing "Sundials" to make use of Assimulo

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

Firstly i should probably state the reason I'm doing this: i want to experiment with some different differential equation solvers to compare efficiency and memory usage for a project I'm working on. As such i wanted to install Assimulo as it makes use of a suite of solvers and is very user friendly.

Prior to installing it, I found I needed to install "sundials":

https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/download/download.html

I downloaded it, untarred it and installed it using a "-fPIC" flag since I'm using 64-bit ubuntu. The installation "appears" to have gone ok, with no exit status messages.

I then installed assimulo, using these instructions:

http://www.jmodelica.org/assimulo_home/installation.html

i specified "usr/local/lib" as the path where sundials was installed, as this was the path it said it had been installed to in the terminal when the script was run.

To check it was working, i downloaded and installed nose to perform a nosetest, but, it is telling me there is something wrong. A part of the error is:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named sundials)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in            loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in      importFromPath
  return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
 mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/assimulo/tests/test_examples.py", line  21, in <module>
 from assimulo.examples import *
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/assimulo/examples/cvode_gyro.py", line 22, in <module>
 from assimulo.solvers import CVode
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/assimulo/solvers/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
 from sundials import IDA, CVode
 ImportError: No module named sundials
```

The other five errors reported by nose are very similar. I understand what its saying in the sense it appears the module is not in the right place, but how do i fix it?

If anyone could help id be very grateful. Ive had an absolute nightmare with this over the past few days. I'm very new to linux and have been trying my best, but everything i install just never seems to work.

OS: Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.
Python version: 2.7
Numpy/Scipy are installed.

edit: here's how i installed assiumulo, and the terminals outputs if it helps:

```
nathan@ubuntu:~/Documents/pythoncode/Assimulo-2.1.1$ sudo python setup.py install     --sundials-home=/usr/local/lib
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "assimulo.implicit_ode" sources
building extension "assimulo.ode" sources
building extension "assimulo.explicit_ode" sources
building extension "assimulo.problem" sources
building extension "assimulo.solvers.euler" sources
building extension "assimulo.lib.dopri5" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/assimulo/thirdparty/hairer/dopri5-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "assimulo.lib.rodas" sources
f2py options: []
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/assimulo/thirdparty/hairer/rodas-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
building extension "assimulo.lib.radau5" sources
f2py options: []
 adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.c' to sources.
 adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7' to include_dirs.
 adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/assimulo/thirdparty/hairer/radau5-f2pywrappers.f' to     sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_py
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
customize LaheyFCompiler
Could not locate executable lf95
customize PGroupFCompiler
Could not locate executable pgfortran
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize NAGFCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/f95
customize VastFCompiler
customize CompaqFCompiler
Could not locate executable fort
customize IntelItaniumFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
running scons
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Assimulo-2.1.1.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Assimulo-2.1.1.egg-info
running install_clib
customize UnixCCompiler
nathan@ubuntu:~/Documents/pythoncode/Assimulo-2.1.1$
```

Answer (score 0):

When installing assimulo try only `/usr` as sundials-home directory.
I have searched per example for the file `cvodes.h` of the sundials module, which was located at `/usr/include/cvodes`. What to use for the sundials-home directory is the parent directory of the include directory, so `/usr`.